# BEST way to convert a month string to an int in MFC

Tags: mfc

In MFC, what is the BEST way to convert a month string to an int, e.g. April to 4? "BEST" here could mean shortest in code, fastest in execution or least memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this would be the fastest in execution or least memory usage, but I feel it is pretty short and simple.

```
int ToNumber(LPCTSTR lpMonthName)
{
   COleDateTime datetime;
   datetime.ParseDateTime(CString(_T("1 ")) + lpMonthName + _T("2000"),VAR_DATEVALUEONLY,LANG_USER_DEFAULT );
   return datetime.GetMonth();
}
```

I got the idea from how I have seen it done in C#

```
DateTime.ParseExact(month, "MMMM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture ).Month
```